# MongoDB connection error when I try to install any gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongomapper

I am trying to run Rails 3.2.3 using gem 1.8.23, Ruby 1.9.2p318 (2012-02-14 revision 34678) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0], MongoDB 1.6.2 with MongoMapper 0.11.0 and heroku.
I am able to start the rails server and use mongoDB both on development and on heroku. But whenever I try to install anything new (bootstrap for instance) or run 'rails s' command, I get the following error (pasted below). I assume it has something to do with mongodb and or mongo mapper. I have also enclosed the config files. I've been stuck with this since couple of days and any hints or ideas are highly appreciated. Unfortunately, this is my first RoR app and hence I may sound really stupid.

Error:

```
new-host:talker Name$ rails g bootstrap:install
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from  at /Users/Name/Projects/talker/config/environment.rb:12)
/Users/Name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/mongo-1.6.2/lib/mongo/networking.rb:330:in `rescue in receive_message_on_socket': Operation failed with the following exception: connection closed (Mongo::ConnectionFailure)
    from /Users/Name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/mongo-1.6.2/lib/mongo/networking.rb:322:in `receive_message_on_socket'
    from /Users/Name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/mongo-1.6.2/lib/mongo/networking.rb:188:in `receive_header'
    from /Users/Name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/mongo-1.6.2/lib/mongo/networking.rb:175:in `receive'
    from /Users/Name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/mongo-1.6.2/lib/mongo/networking.rb:139:in `receive_message'
    from /Users/Name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/mongo-1.6.2/lib/mongo/cursor.rb:469:in `block in send_initial_query'
    from /Users/Name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/mongo-1.6.2/lib/mongo/util/logging.rb:36:in `instrument'
    from /Users/Name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/mongo-1.6.2/lib/mongo/cursor.rb:467:in `send_initial_query'
    from /Users/Name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/mongo-1.6.2/lib/mongo/cursor.rb:458:in `refresh'
    from /Users/Name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/mongo-1.6.2/lib/mongo/cursor.rb:128:in `next'
    from /Users/Name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/mongo-1.6.2/lib/mongo/db.rb:511:in `command'
    from /Users/Name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/mongo-1.6.2/lib/mongo/connection.rb:628:in `check_is_master'
    from /Users/Name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/mongo-1.6.2/lib/mongo/connection.rb:402:in `connect'
    from /Users/Name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/mongo-1.6.2/lib/mongo/connection.rb:589:in `setup'
    from /Users/Name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/mongo-1.6.2/lib/mongo/connection.rb:114:in `initialize'
    from /Users/Name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/mongo_mapper-0.11.1/lib/mongo_mapper/connection.rb:75:in `new'
    from /Users/Name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/mongo_mapper-0.11.1/lib/mongo_mapper/connection.rb:75:in `connect'
    from /Users/Name/Projects/talker/config/initializers/mogo.rb:28:in `'
    from /Users/Name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
    from /Users/Name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
    from /Users/Name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/Name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
    from /Users/Name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:588:in `block (2 levels) in '
    from /Users/Name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `each'
    from /Users/Name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `block in '
    from /Users/Name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/Name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/Name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/Name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /Users/Name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/Name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/Name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/Name/Projects/talker/config/environment.rb:12:in `'
    from /Users/Name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require'
    from /Users/Name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
    from /Users/Name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:25:in `'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `'
new-host:talker Name$
```

environment.rb

`require File.expand_path('../application', FILE)
Talker::Application.initialize!`

mongo.rb

`MongoMapper.config = { 
  Rails.env => { 'uri' => ENV['MONGOHQ_URL'] || 'mongodb://localhost:28017' } }
MongoMapper.connect(Rails.env)
if defined?(PhusionPassenger)
   PhusionPassenger.on_event(:starting_worker_process) do |forked|
     MongoMapper.connection.connect if forked
   end
end`

Comment: It's definitely failing to connect to MongoDB. Is MongoDB running? The line MongoMapper.connect(Rails.env) is where it's failing.

Comment: I can browse to localhost:28017 and view all... don't understand why it would throw the error..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your config file says to connect to localhost:28017, but that's the web console. You probably want localhost:27017.

Comment: I tried that too... I get /Users/Name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/common.rb:156:in `split': bad URI(is not URI?): (URI::InvalidURIError)

Comment: You need 'mongodb://localhost:27017'

Comment: Yup... tried this { 'uri' => ENV['MONGOHQ_URL'] || 'mongodb://localhost:27017' } and I get the bad URI error.

Comment: Are you still having trouble with this?

Comment: Well.. I've basically comment out everything in my mongohq.rb in development environment but include it in production (on heroku)... no idea why it blows up in dev environment for me...